# How to run cmd command just inside python tkinter listbox without console shell?

Tags: python, shell, tkinter, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to run a cmd command inside my program GUI without shell. The command starts in a separate thread and results shows in a listbox. It works well when run the python file in a shell but it is broken when running created exe file using pyinstaller.

This is the code that runs cmd:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(CMDSTRING, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,creationflags=0x08000000)
if process:
    self.running_thread_checker = process.poll()
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        self.print_listbox(line)  # send this output to the listbox
    process.wait()
```

and CMDSTRING is this command string:

> nodemon index

nodemon is a npm package for nodejs that runs index.js.
it works good when typing this command in command prompt directly and also when running non exe file. but when I create an exe of my python file using pyinstaller, not works.
My suggestion is: Maybe a **shell is required** to run this command. But the question is, Is there any way to get rid of shell when exe file is running. (the parameter *creationflags=0x08000000* also removes shell when executing).

This is pyinstaller command:

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed main.py

Comment: Without a console, `print(line)` is useless.  Also your code does not have a listbox and the output of the subprocess is not inserted into any listbox.

Comment: @asw1668 Yes u right. But it is a sample. I mean that I use this result in my GUI.

Comment: So better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you put the `index.js` along with the generated exe?